# Joomla to Wordpress migration issue

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, migrate

I've already have the template, and have not completely migrated over to WordPress, all my articles are still in Joomla.

I want to fully migrate over from WordPress, but am currently having problems with setting up menus and sub menus in the WordPress template.

Maybe it would be better to re-migrate all my stuff. Are there any free simple in use plugins or could you suggest me how to perform it programmatically?

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Offtopic, but may I ask what is the reason you are migrating to Wordpress?

Comment: I'm not programmer and don't have enough technical skills. Joomla is powerful, but not so intuitive like Wordpress. Just see the comparison goo.gl/EjC0G So I made a decision to move to Wordpress. Hope it's right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these below. Let me know if you have any issues.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fg-joomla-to-wordpress/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/joomla-to-wordpress-migrator/

Comment: Did you tried these plugin? I've found this article on blog http://fuzzythinking.davidmullens.com/content/moving-from-drupal-7-to-wordpress-3-3/ In comments they discussing Cms2Cms service. They say that it's very swift and convenient.

Comment: yeah It's better go on with the one you are comfortable. It does not hurt to try new ones if you are interested.